# How to execute 'make' and 'run' commands on vbg files in Administrator mode on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, vb6

I have a VB6 project which has two components that I need to 'make' before I can 'run' the VB6 project. This involves me right clicking on each of the component (vgb file) and choosing the 'Make' option from the context menu. After that, I then right click on the project that I want to run and choose 'Run'.

I'm using Windows 10 and for some reason, it won't let you modify system registry without being in Administrator mode.

If I right click the vbg file and click 'Make', I get a popup with the message: "`Error accessing the system registry`"

My previous laptop had Windows 7 and I never had problems with the 'make' action.

Is there a way to execute 'make' in Administrator mode?

Comment: Elevate the process responsible for the "make" operation.